# what kind of an approach should I use to extract semantics from a sentence

Tags: nlp

Say for an example there is a sentence "Create a customer in the CRM and set his age to 25 and gender to male.". I would like to extract information like gender is male, age is 25, command is create a customer. How can I do this?

I've tried Semantic role labelers like mate-tools and it cannot extract things like age is 25, gender is male.
Is there a particular way or method or a pipeline I can do this successfully and what kind of an accuracy can I expect?

Comment: You should look at: dependency parsing or Information Extraction (IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your input constrained or are you expecting to parse standard everyday English? If you have to recognise just a few phrases you can get away with a rule-based system backed by a dependency parser (i.e. find the keyword "create", use the parser to work out it is a customer that the user wants created; then match the known attributes of the customer by following the dependencies in a similar way). If the input is unconstrained, you can forget about it.

Comment: thank you for the reply. The user is allowed to enter sentences in standard everyday English. How ever one pattern is the input is always a command.(like create something, edit, delete, etc...)

Comment: Maybe what you want is a domain-specific language. Have a look on stackoverflow for questions tagged `antlr`